# Java InfoBox pane with hyperlink ability not working on first instance

Tags: java, popup, infobox

So I needed an infobox to pop up with info all over my app. I then thought it would be nice to include hyperlinks within those boxes so I looked around an found the following:

```
public class InfoBox{

static Component frmCtsAutomation;
static Point whereToAppear;

public static void infoBox(String infoMessage, String titleBar) {

JLabel labelForPopUp = new JLabel();

JEditorPane ep = new JEditorPane("text/html", infoMessage);    
ep.addHyperlinkListener(new HyperlinkListener(){
    @Override
    public void hyperlinkUpdate(HyperlinkEvent e)
    {
        if (e.getEventType().equals(HyperlinkEvent.EventType.ACTIVATED))
            try {
                Desktop.getDesktop().browse(e.getURL().toURI());
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (URISyntaxException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } // roll your own link launcher or use Desktop if J6+
    }
});
ep.setEditable(false);
ep.setBackground(labelForPopUp.getBackground());


JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frmCtsAutomation, ep, "This is a WARNING: " + titleBar, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
whereToAppear = Main.frmCtsAutomation.getLocation();
}
}
```

This is generally working fine except for the first time it is used. When it launches for the first run it displays nothing but after than it is good to go every single time.

I have moved stuff around/rearranged. Added in setVisable. Also attempted to setVisable on the JEditorPane in another class.

I have looked it over and simply do not see what I am missing here. Any guidance would be much appreciated.

The Component frmCtsAutomation is my main frame for my main GUI. I use it to force the popup to appear wherever it is.

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring the Desktop into a variable like below but your code works fine.

```
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

import javax.swing.JEditorPane;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.event.HyperlinkEvent;
import javax.swing.event.HyperlinkListener;

public class InfoBox
{

    public InfoBox()
    {
        infoBox("Test", "Test Title");
    }

    static Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();

    public static void infoBox(String infoMessage, String titleBar)
    {

        JLabel labelForPopUp = new JLabel();

        JEditorPane ep = new JEditorPane("text/html", infoMessage);
        ep.addHyperlinkListener(new HyperlinkListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void hyperlinkUpdate(HyperlinkEvent e)
            {
                if(e.getEventType().equals(HyperlinkEvent.EventType.ACTIVATED))
                try
                {
                    desktop.browse(e.getURL().toURI());
                }
                catch(IOException e1)
                {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                catch(URISyntaxException e1)
                {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } // roll your own link launcher or use Desktop if J6+
            }
        });
        ep.setEditable(false);
        ep.setBackground(labelForPopUp.getBackground());

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ep, "This is a WARNING: " + titleBar, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new InfoBox();
    }

}
```

Comment: Just tried that and still failing the first time it comes up. The box opens, the title is there, and the button but all the text in the box is missing. Again this only happens for the first call after that it works like a charm. Totally stumped.

Answer (score 0):

I still could not get this to work so I moved the infobox code to it's own class and then it all started working.

Scratch ALL that.... the issue is still there but now I see a pattern.

I have four different "windows" that I call upon from a main "window". The popups work the first time every time when called from the main window but if I call it from any thread it does what I originally reported. So calling from any of the GUI(windows) will work but from a thread they do fail to show up on the first call but all subsequent calls works.